# ASP.NET Consolidated Report

Tags: asp.net, reporting

We have an ASP.NET 2 application and at the moment for the reporting, we are utilising DataSet/DataTable taking some storedprocedure/query and display on the screen (grids). For the graphics, we are using Dundas Chart component and again we are utilising DataSet/DataTable to display it. These thing has been running well ... no issue.

Now, we are having a challenge that every single report that we produce above (grid or graph), the user wants to consolidate into 1 single click solution which means if they click the "Consolidated Report" it will produce the page as well (grid/graph) into 1 page. But the issue is that the user wants use the display (grid/graph) and download into 1 file. It could Ms Words/Ms Excell.

How we are going to achieve this?

I am thinking to do as follow:
1. Convert everything to use the Reporting Services (client) .. or
2. Is it possible to do like convert the page/grapf into Word/Excel into a single page? Is there any other solution?

The issue is that the we have simple stored procedures to get the data source out and then we are using that data and do the massive data manipulation in DataSet/DataTable (loop through the records, create a new dataset and manipulate etc etc) and then to construct the final report and display on the screen.

I am appreciated your comment.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution will be integrating the HTML into a PDF.

You can convert the HTML generated into PDF easily with [ABCPdf from WebSuperGoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) (I suspect that other solutions can work, but I have only used this product)

See this [live demo](http://www.abcpdfeditor.com/), and select "Add URL" and point to your URL or [check out this example](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm)